# Uso de "!" en PHP

Tags: php, condiciones

He buscado tema referente en StackOverflow pero solo he encontrado lo siguiente [Double not (!!) operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127260/double-not-operator-in-php).

Cuál es la funcionalidad de este operador `!` en:

```
if(!empty($_GET)){
}
```

o

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
}
```

Qué tiene de especial, qué ocasión u error evita.

Pueden explicarme :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partimos de que la [función](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php) `empty()` analiza y determina si una variable esta vacía

Entonces para el caso de

```
if(empty($_POST['nombre'])){
   ...... código si la variable viene vacía
}
```

Estamos validando que si la variable `$_POST['nombre']` viene vacía entonces se ejecute un bloque de código determinado

Ahora el [operador](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php) `!` aplicado a la variable `!empty($_POST['nombre'])` invierte la naturaleza de la propia función que pasa de ser *verificar si viene vacía* a *verificar que no este vacía*

Por ejemplo

```
$numero = 1;

if(!empty($numero)){
    echo "Variable no vacía";
}else{
    echo "variable vacía";
}
```

El código anterior devolverá `variable no vacía` por que con el operador `!` estamos indicando *si la variable $numero no esta vacía* por lo cual se cumple la primer condición e imprime dicho mensaje

Comment: Gracias Amig@, muy bien explicado :)

Answer (score 1):

La función del el operador lógico `NOT` es negar la expresión que establece la sentencia `if`. Más información sobre operadores lógicos [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php).

Para tu caso:

```
if(!empty($_GET)){
}
```

Se cumplirá la sentencia `if` si `$_GET` no está vacío.

Comment: El detalle final que agregaste aclaro todas las dudas sobre este "!" operador, gracias amig@ :)

Answer (score 1):

Como ya han dicho los compañeros, **`!`** equivale al [operador lógico `not`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php).

Para la **comprensión**, en código PHP si cuando ves `!` delante de cualquier cosa, lo cambias por *no ...*, ya entenderás de qué se trata. De modo que tu código:

```
if(!empty($_GET)){
    //haz esto
}
```

Se puede entender así en lenguaje coloquial: *si `$_GET` no está vacío ... haz esto...*

Si le quitas el operador de negación, ocurriría lo contrario claro está:

```
if(empty($_GET)){
    //haz esto
}
```

*Si `$_GET` está vacío ... haz esto*.

### Uso interesante

Hay un uso interesante de `empty` cuando trabajamos con valores provenientes de `$_GET` o de `$_POST` u otros. Se trata de combinarlo con un *operador ternario*, para de ese modo verificar el estado de los datos y al mismo tiempo guardar su valor en una variable.

Es lo que suelo hacer por ejemplo ante datos `$_GET` que son obligatorios para lanzar ciertos bloques de código. Supongamos un escenario donde `id` y el `name` son obligatorios y si vienen vacíos el código no debería continuar:

```
$id =   !empty($_GET['id'])   ? $_GET['id']   : NULL;
$name = !empty($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : NULL;
```

Aquí lo que se dice es algo como: *si `$_GET['id']` no está vacío, guárdame su valor en la variable `$id`, de lo contrario que `$id`  sea `NULL`*.

Luego, si para el código se requiere que haya datos para el `id` y para `name`, se haría esto:

```
if ($id && $name) {
    $date = !empty($_GET['date']) ? $_GET['date'] : NULL;
    //Trabajar con las variables $id, $name, $date
} else {
    echo "No se puede seguir, faltan datos esenciales";
}
```

Y cuando se necesiten los valores, puesto que ya los guardamos mediante el ternario, usamos las variables creadas allí.

**Nótese** que el valor de `$date` lo obtengo dentro del `if`, porque es solamente en ese bloque donde lo voy a necesitar. Un principio importante en programación es no declarar o crear recursos sin antes estar seguro de que los vas a usar.

La anterior evaluación se puede hacer también directamente actuando sobre los valores que vienen en `$_GET`:

```
if (!empty($_GET['id'] && !empty($_GET['name']) {
    //aquí, hay que hacer uso de nuevo de $_GET['id'] y de $_GET['name']
} else {

}
```

Pero es más feo y menos práctico, porque luego, cuando necesites los valores, tendrás que tirar de nuevo de `$_GET['id']` ... etc.

---

### `!` no siempre está solo

Hay que decir también que `!` no trabaja siempre sólo. Puede que lo veas en otros escenarios, por ejemplo:

```
if ($a != $b) {

}
```

O bien:

```
if ($a !== $b) {

}
```

En esos dos casos hablamos entonces de [*operadores de comparación*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php).

El primero es fácil de entender, si usamos la técnica aplicada al principio. Significa *si `$a` no es igual a `$b`*.

El segundo significa por una parte lo mismo que el primero: *si `$a` no es igual a `$b`*, pero, al usarse dos veces el signo `==`, se indica que no sólo compare los valores, sino también los tipos. O sea, *si `$a` no es igual a `$b` o si no son del mismo tipo*. En PHP esto se llama **comparación estricta**.

Veamos algunos ejemplos.

Aquí las variables tienen el mismo valor `1`, pero una es del tipo `string` y la otra del tipo `int`:

```
$a="1";
$b=1;

if ($a!=$b){
    echo "valor no es igual";
}else{
    echo "valor es igual";
}  

echo PHP_EOL;
if ($a!==$b){
    echo "valor o tipo no es igual";
}else{
    echo "valor es igual y tipo es igual";
}
```

**Salida:**

```
valor es igual
valor o tipo no es igual
```

Comparemos ahora con valores del mismo tipo:

```
$a=1;
$b=1;
echo PHP_EOL;

if ($a!=$b){
    echo "valor no es igual";
}else{
    echo "valor es igual";
}  

echo PHP_EOL;
if ($a!==$b){
    echo "valor o tipo no es igual";
}else{
    echo "valor es igual y tipo es igual";
}
```

**Salida:**

```
valor es igual
valor es igual y tipo es igual
```

Answer (score 0):

**!** hace negación 
**empty** verifica si esta vacio
**$_GET , $_POST , $_PUT** etc son los métodos **http** que usas para pasar datos del frontend al backend

$_GET son recibidas por la URL
a diferencia de los demás que lo hace internamente...

```
if(!empty($_GET["variable"])){
    echo "Variable no vacía";
}else{
    echo "variable vacía";
}



if(empty($_POST["variable"])){
    echo "Variable vacía";
}else{
    echo "variable no vacía";
}
```